C code for solving a 15-puzzle gives a segmentation fault when it tries to show the paths for each update to the puzzle
I have a code that is supposed to show the paths in solving a 15-puzzle after showing the initial state and goal state. However, while it does show the initial state and goal state, it gives a segmentation fault instead of printing out the path.
Here is the code below:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 4
#define NxN (N*N)
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

struct node {
    int tiles[N][N];
    int f, g, h;
    short zero_row, zero_column;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *parent;
};

int goal_rows[NxN];
int goal_columns[NxN];
struct node *start,*goal;
struct node *open = NULL, *closed = NULL;
struct node *succ_nodes[4];

void print_a_node(struct node *pnode) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<N;j++) 
            printf("%2d ", pnode->tiles[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct node *initialize(char **argv){
    int i,j,k,index, tile;
    struct node *pnode;

    pnode=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    index = 1;
    for (j=0;j<N;j++)
        for (k=0;k<N;k++) {
            tile=atoi(argv[index++]);
            pnode->tiles[j][k]=tile;
            if(tile==0) {
                pnode->zero_row=j;
                pnode->zero_column=k;
            }
        }
    pnode->f=0;
    pnode->g=0;
    pnode->h=0;
    pnode->next=NULL;
    pnode->parent=NULL;
    start=pnode;
    printf("initial state\n");
    print_a_node(start);

    pnode=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    goal_rows[0]=3;
    goal_columns[0]=3;

    for(index=1; index<NxN; index++){
        j=(index-1)/N;
        k=(index-1)%N;
        goal_rows[index]=j;
        goal_columns[index]=k;
        pnode->tiles[j][k]=index;
    }
    pnode->tiles[N-1][N-1]=0;
    pnode->f=0;
    pnode->g=0;
    pnode->h=0;
    pnode->next=NULL;
    goal=pnode; 
    printf("goal state\n");
    print_a_node(goal);

    return start;
}

void merge_to_open() { 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (succ_nodes[i] == NULL) {
            continue;
        }
        struct node *insert_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        memcpy(insert_node->tiles, succ_nodes[i]->tiles, NxN*sizeof(int));
        insert_node->f = succ_nodes[i]->f;
        insert_node->g = succ_nodes[i]->g;
        insert_node->h = succ_nodes[i]->h;
        insert_node->zero_row = succ_nodes[i]->zero_row;
        insert_node->zero_column = succ_nodes[i]->zero_column;
        insert_node->parent = succ_nodes[i]->parent;

        if (open == NULL) {
            open = insert_node;
            continue;
        }

        struct node *temp = open;

        int status = FALSE;

        while (temp != NULL && temp->next != NULL) {
            if (insert_node->f < temp->next->f) {
                insert_node->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = insert_node;
                status = TRUE;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        if (status == FALSE) {
            temp->next = insert_node;
        }
    }
}

void swap(int row1,int column1,int row2,int column2, struct node * pnode){
    int tile = pnode->tiles[row1][column1];
    pnode->tiles[row1][column1]=pnode->tiles[row2][column2];
    pnode->tiles[row2][column2]=tile;
}

int manhattan(int entry, int row, int column) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NxN; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NxN; j++) {
            if(goal->tiles[i][j] == entry) {
                return abs(row - i) + abs(column - j);
            }
        }
    }
}

void update_fgh(int t) {
    struct node *pnode = succ_nodes[t];
    
    if (pnode -> parent != NULL) {
        pnode->g = pnode->parent->g + 1;
    } else {
        pnode->g = 1;
    }

    int misplaced = 0, distance = 0, correct = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NxN; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NxN; j++) {
            correct++;
            if (pnode->tiles[j][i] != correct) {
                misplaced++;
            }

            if (pnode->tiles[j][i] == 0) {
                distance = 0;
            } else {
                distance = manhattan(pnode->tiles[j][i], j, i);
            }
        }
    }

    if (misplaced > distance) {
        pnode->h = misplaced;
    } else {
        pnode->h = distance;
    }

    pnode->f = pnode->g + pnode->h;
}

void move_down(struct node * pnode){
    if (pnode->zero_row + 1 < N) {
        swap(pnode->zero_row, pnode->zero_column, pnode->zero_row + 1, pnode->zero_column, pnode);
        pnode->zero_row++;
    } else {
        pnode = NULL;
    }
}

void move_right(struct node * pnode){
    if (pnode->zero_column + 1 < N) {
        swap(pnode->zero_row, pnode->zero_column, pnode->zero_row, pnode->zero_column + 1, pnode);
        pnode->zero_column++;
    } else {
        pnode = NULL;
    }
}

void move_up(struct node * pnode){
    if (pnode->zero_row - 1 > -1) {
        swap(pnode->zero_row, pnode->zero_column, pnode->zero_row - 1, pnode->zero_column, pnode);
        pnode->zero_row--;
    } else {
        pnode = NULL;
    }
}

void move_left(struct node * pnode){
    if (pnode->zero_column - 1 > -1) {
        swap(pnode->zero_row, pnode->zero_column, pnode->zero_row, pnode->zero_column - 1, pnode);
        pnode->zero_column--;
    } else {
        pnode = NULL;
    }
}

void expand(struct node *selected) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        succ_nodes[i] = NULL;
    }

    move_down(succ_nodes[0]);
    move_right(succ_nodes[1]);
    move_up(succ_nodes[2]);
    move_left(succ_nodes[3]);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        update_fgh(i);
    }
}

int nodes_same(struct node *a,struct node *b) {
    int flg=FALSE;
    if (memcmp(a->tiles, b->tiles, sizeof(int)*NxN) == 0)
        flg=TRUE;
    return flg;
}
 
void filter(int i, struct node *pnode_list){ 
    struct node *pnode = succ_nodes[i];
    struct node *temp = pnode_list;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (nodes_same(pnode, temp)) {
            pnode = NULL;
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    int iter,cnt;
    struct node *copen, *cp, *solution_path;
    int ret, i, pathlen=0, index[N-1];

    solution_path=NULL;
    start=initialize(argv);
    open=start; 

    iter=0; 
    while (open!=NULL) {
        copen=open;
        open=open->next;

        if(nodes_same(copen,goal)){
            do{
                copen->next=solution_path;
                solution_path=copen;
                copen=copen->parent;
                pathlen++;
            } while(copen!=NULL);
            printf("Path (length=%d):\n", pathlen); 
            copen=solution_path;

            break;
        }
        expand(copen);

        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            filter(i,open);
            filter(i,closed);
        }

        merge_to_open();

        copen->next=closed;
        closed=copen;

        iter++;
        if(iter %1000 == 0)
            printf("iter %d\n", iter);
    }
    return 0;
}

I used these command line arguments for running the program:
2 3 0 4 1 6 7 8 5 9 10 12 13 14 11 15

When I run a gdb debugging of the program, it prints out this (the value I passed as pnode in the program is succ_nodes[0]):
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555555940 in move_down (pnode=0x0) at problem1.c:172
172             if (pnode->zero_row + 1 < N) {

I assume this occurs for all the move functions with the pnode statements. Can you help me figure out a way to fix this?

pnode=0x0.......

There's much too much code here. Look at void move_down(). The else operation sets the parameter variable pnode to NULL, then the function terminates. Same observation about _up(), _left() and _right()... This achieves nothing except to make the code bloated... Suggest you withdraw this question and review this code yourself to eliminate as much as you can, then ask again if there's still a problem. Don't try to learn C by guessing and hoping things will work out. Every symbol typed when writing code, including whitespace, is significant.

There is no code where you ever assign a node to succ_nodes[i]. expand sets all four of these to NULL and then calls move_down with the first of these NULLs, but that function expects a non-NULL pointer: it de-references that NULL as if it is a valid node pointer. Hence the undefined behavior. I don't see any code that really expands nodes, i.e. where succ_nodes is populated with neighbor nodes.
